# FreeMarker hash lookup using object graph notation

Tags: struts2, freemarker

I have 2 variables in parameters map populated from a struts2 tag, as follows:

1. `obj` - A java object with various child objects. It can be treated as a hash in freemarker template.
2. `displayProperty` - A string containing property name inside the `obj`. The name can be object graph containing multiple levels of drill down.

I want to display the given property of the `obj` using freemarker template. For example if `displayProperty` is `entity.name`, then it should essentially print value of `obj.entity.name`.

My freemarker template is `${obj[displayProperty]}`, but it fails when `displayProperty` contains a dot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be `('obj.' + displayProperty)?eval`, although it involves generic expression parsing and so is not the fastest. The fastest running solution would be to create a custom method (`TemplateMethodModelEx` implementation) that you could use like `${walkProperty(obj, displayProperty)}`, which would split the string at the dots, and call `TempalteHashModel.get` in a loop.

Comment: Thanks. `eval` is working fine. Performance is not an issue for us.